# Is there a covering lemma that can help here?

Tags: measure-theory

After stuffing around with the definitions for awhile, my friend and I managed to reduce a question on the latest measure theory assignment to proving the following:

> **Claim.** Suppose $X$ is a locally compact hausdorff space. Let $\mu : \mathcal{B}_X \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ denote a measure that's inner regular on Borel sets. Then $\mu$ is outer regular on Borel sets.

Our idea is as follows. Consider a borel set $A \subseteq X$ and a $\varepsilon > 0$. We're trying to find an open set $U \supseteq A$ such that $\mu(U) - \mu(A) < \varepsilon$.

To do this, consider a monotone sequence of compact sets $$K_0 \subseteq K_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq A$$ such that $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(K_i) = \mu(A).$ Now look for a theorem that allows us deduce that for all $\delta>0$, the set $$\mathcal{U}_\delta := \{U \subseteq X : U\, \mathrm{open} \;\&\; \mu(U)<\delta\}$$ covers $X$. If this is true, then each of the $K_i$ can be covered by finitely many elements of $\mathcal{U}_\delta$. Our thinking was then to throw some kind of covering lemma at the problem that allows us to cover each $K_i$ efficiently by elements of $\mathcal{U}_\delta$. We then take the union of all these coverings, possibly with some combinatorial funny-business to guarantee that the measure of the union of all these coverings only exceeds the measure of $A$ by a small amount that's a function of $\delta$. We then choose $\delta$ sufficiently small to guarantee that it's within $\varepsilon$ of our goal.

> **Question.** Is there is a covering lemma that can help us here? In particular, it should guarantee that finite covers by open sets with measure at most $\delta$ can be replaced with more efficient covers that only overestimate the the measure of the set being covered by a small amount.

I had a look at the main covering lemmas that seem to be out there, but as far as I can tell they're all tied to $\mathbb{R}^n$, or are at least dependent on having a metric structure around.

Comment: Remark: we just proved the claim by a much easier method, by considering a sufficiently large compact subset of $A^c$. But I'm still interested in proving this via some kind of covering lemma though, just for the sake of the lemma.